# PBI/DAX - Filter on selected leaf node

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with 2 columns: `source` and `target`. Sample:

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| Company | Plant A |
| Company | Plant B |
| Company | Plant C |
| Plant A | Building X |
| Plant A | Building Y |
| Plant B | Building R |
| Plant B | Building S |

I created the column `isLeaf` to check for leaf nodes (True or False):

```
IsLeaf = 
    VAR CurrentNode = FullHierarchy[Target]
    RETURN CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( FullHierarchy ),
        ALL ( FullHierarchy ),
        FullHierarchy[Source] = CurrentNode
    ) = 0
```

Also, the path is calculated using the `PATH()` function.

Next, I created the *disconnected* table `Leafs` containing only the leaf nodes:

```
Leafs = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        FILTER(FullHierarchy, FullHierarchy[IsLeaf]),
        "LeafNode", FullHierarchy[Target]
    )
```

This is the result: 2 disconnected tables.

[image: model]

My goal is to have 2 visuals: a slicer based on `Leafs` and a table based on `FullHierarchy`. Selecting a leaf shows only the items that are directly or indirectly connected to it (i.e. part of it's path).

[image: visuals]

The statement to do so would be something like:

```
PATHCONTAINS(
    LOOKUPVALUE(FullHierarchy[Path],
                FullHierarchy[Target]
                [Selected Node]),
    FullHierarchy[Target])
```

The statement above would lookup the path for the selected leaf node, and then check if the node in the table was part of it, to decide whether or not to show it.

I've tried countless of variations, but have unable to implement this. Any ideas, suggestions, etc would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Sample pbix file is available [here](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/Vj1WZo3l#link).

**Update**

To clarify, selecting a leaf node should give return all connected nodes, all the way to the top (i.e. the full lineage).

For example, selecting *Machine E2* should return

- Machine E2
- Section E
- Building A
- Plant C
- Company

More visually:

[image: tree]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the definition of your calculated table as follows:

```
Leafs = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        FILTER(FullHierarchy, FullHierarchy[IsLeaf]),
        "LeafNode", FullHierarchy[Target],
        "Path", FullHierarchy[Path]
    )
```

New measure:

```
Measure = 

VAR vals = VALUES(Leafs[Path])
VAR check = SELECTEDVALUE(FullHierarchy[Target])
RETURN 
SUMX(vals, IF(SEARCH(check,Leafs[Path],,BLANK())>0,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't quite what I'm looking for. This only returns the node connected directly to it, while the goal was to return all connected nodes, directly and indirectly. I've updated the original post to clarify it further.

Comment: Is the slicer single single or multi select? In your example, when selecting Machine 2, should the other rows be returned where the value is present in Source, Target or both?

Comment: The slicer is single value. The values that are returned are the rows where the target is part of the path of the selected leaf node.

Comment: I'll update my answer now.

Comment: Out of interest, is your hierarchy visual d3 or Vega or something else?

Comment: The hierarchy is actually a visual from AppSource called [Tree](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA200000621?tab=Overview) ([repo](https://ck-corp.github.io/TreePowerBIVisual))

Comment: I know the one - thanks. Let me know if the new solution works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on David's answer, this is the measure I ended up implementing, after which I filter on `inLineage=1` :

```
inLineage = 
    VAR PathLeafNode = LOOKUPVALUE(FullHierarchy[Path], FullHierarchy[Target], [Selected Node])
    VAR IsInPath = PATHCONTAINS(PathLeafNode, SELECTEDVALUE(FullHierarchy[Target]))
    VAR dummy = VALUES(Leafs[LeafNode])
RETURN IF(HASONEVALUE(Leafs[LeafNode]),SUMX(dummy, IF(IsInPath,1,0)),1)
```